# Azure Notification Hub and setting expirations for Device Installations

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Firstly, I'm trying to set a Device Installation expiry date so that after a period of time the device is removed from my Notification Hub instance.  This way, the notification hub is not filled with devices that are no longer used, therefore optimising my device registration quota.

I've searched high and low for a solution to this and I'm hoping someone is able to help me.

I've tried setting the ExpirationDate on a new Installation object but this does not seem to work.  The expiry date is always infinity.

I then read I need to set the Registration Time To Live at the hub level, but I'm unable to find the appropriate libraries to do this.  I've installed the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management library, but this does not have the methods I need to update the TTL property.

Am I correct in my approach?  That is, should I be trying to set the expiration date (or TTL) for an Installation or should I be manually calling a method to delete/remove the installation from the notification hub?  If the TTL approach is correct, how do I go about setting this for each device registration/installation from code?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**  So I managed to change the TTL at the hub level using the Service Bus Explorer tool and I can see a device Installation has its expiry set to the new TTL (set to one day for my testing).  However, even setting this TTL doesn't appear to automatically remove an Installation once it has expired.  So an additional question is, how do you maintain the list of registered devices in the Notification Hub so you don't end up with a heap of devices that aren't used and therefore consuming your allowed quota?  Do I need to manually remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Azure Notification Hub automatically removes Installations/Registrations once they have expired.  By setting the Time To Live at the Hub level (via Service Bus Explorer) I was able to set an expiration date for each installation.  To update the expiration date, you just need to perform an update on the installation.

Comment: What happens when the installation IDs are unknown or don't exist anymore?